# https gives 404 error

Tags: php, nginx, https

I'd like to deal with the 404 error that nginx gives if a user tries to navigate to my site using https instead of http. I do not have a secure section to my site and do not need one. I have no SSL certificate and simply want all https requests to redirect to http equivalent.

Is this something I can do in .htaccess?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `nginx` support `.htaccess` . So in your `nginx conf` add this. It will redirect all https request http.

```
server {
       listen 443;
       server_name  yourdomain.com;
       rewrite ^(.*) http://$host$1 permanent;
 }
```

You could use this in `.htaccess` if your webserver was `apache`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```